# Django ORM .get() method not working, but .filter() does

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, tdd

I'm trying to write some code to return a Category object to a template. No matter what i try, my test keeps failing. I get the "Category matching query does not exist" exception. I tried using filter instead to see if i misspelled something, and to my surprise it worked perfectly and returned the object i was looking for, only problem is that it was in a query set. I know .filter().first() will work, but isn't that kinda hacky? Maybe i just need an extra set of eyes and did something stupid.
Here's the Test:

```
def test_featured_page_receives_correct_list(self):
    #Featured cat
    c1 = Category.objects.create(title='featured')
    #Featured mod 1
    mod1 = Mod.objects.create(modname='ModTest', author='TestAuthor', link='https://www.google.com/', dev_site='https://www.google.com/', minecraft_ver='1.6.4')
    mod1.categories.add(c1)
    #Featured mod 2
    mod2 = Mod.objects.create(modname='ModTest2', author='TestAuthor', link='https://www.google.com/', dev_site='https://www.google.com/', minecraft_ver='1.7.2')
    mod2.categories.add(c1)

    response = self.client.get('/home/')
    self.assertEqual(response.context['featured'], c1)
```

And here's the very simple view code:

```
def featured(request):
    featured_cat = Category.objects.get(title='featured')
    return render(request, 'featured.html', {'featured': featured_cat})
```

Edit: It's python 3, and the latest stable version of django.

Comment: Silly set of questions: are you abs sure that when you're calling `.get` it exists? Which line is it failing on? the `featured_cat =` part? Can you show us what it looked like when you tried the `.filter` side by side with the `.get`?

Comment: Is the import of "Category" the same in your test and view? That's a common class name...

Comment: Yeah absolutely sure, i got the right import i have .get working in a different view, for the same purpose. Yes it is failing on the featured cat part. I'm not quest sure what you mean by 'Does it exist', i think it does. I ended up changing it to just send back a list of the mods though and searching the catagory like this: Mod.objects.filter(categories__title__startswith='featured') works too.

Comment: Can you add traceback?